# AngularJS: How to separate animation code from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

In one of my controllers, I have a method triggers "grayOutBox".

```
class Box

  ...

  grayOutBox: (delay = false) ->
    @state = ''
    if delay
      $timeout =>
        @state = 'grayedOut'
      , 2300
    else
      @state = 'grayedOut'
```

Depending on what method calls it, there may be some animations playing which we need to wait for to finish before graying-out the box. (Other scope changes before this method is called trigger ng-enter animation events.)

Since this timeout code doesn't belong in the controller, I'm wondering how to separate this wait elegantly and using Angular's paradigms, with the $timeout being conditional based on the method parameters.

Comment: please have a look at http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html - there the angular way of animation is explained in detail.